# Add meta tag with name and content to my html-page with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT but I have to use it to add a meta tag to my existing html-page.

My existsing html-page looks like this

```
<html class="no-js" lang="de-DE">
   <head>
      <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta charset="utf-8">      
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
   </head>
```

I have to add another meta tag to this html page so that the new html-page looks like this.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="de-DE">
   <head>
      <meta name="webcode" content="od1234">
      <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta charset="utf-8">      
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
   </head>
```

Can somebody show me the xslt-Script to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which xslt version and processor do you use ?

Comment: You won't be able to use XSLT on your current HTML page, as it is not well-formed XML. The `meta` tags are not closed. For example, it should be `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. Are you able to correct this? Thanks!

Comment: The xslt version is 1.0

Comment: I am sorry. It is a jsp-page and not html

Answer (score 0):

```
**Xslt2.0**
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
<html>
<head>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</head>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head">
<xsl:element name="meta">
<xsl:attribute name="name">webcode</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="content">od1234</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```